# file downloading from ftp server in iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ftp, ios5

can we download a file from a ftp server using iOS sdk's API or by any other way.
i know that through http request we can download files from server. so can we download file from ftp server in same way or is there any different sets of API for ftp.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://user:password@host:port/path"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Then you will get the file into `data`.

---

**SWIFT:**

```
var url = URL(string: "ftp://testUser:testPassword@191.122.0.12:20/ScheduleProject/Database/User.json")  //sudo code: URL(string: "ftp://user:password@host:port/path")
var data: Data? = nil
if let anUrl = url {
    data = Data(contentsOf: anUrl)
}
```

Comment: Please let me know a example string.