# How to download FTP file in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, ftp

I am not able to download FTP file from server. Is there any ways to download.
 I have used URLSession but doesn't helped at all
I have gone through this link http://sweettutos.com/2015/11/06/networking-in-swift-how-to-download-a-file-with-nsurlsession/ but doesn't working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612724/file-downloading-from-ftp-server-in-ios-application

Comment: @QuocNguyen its working.... Please put it as answer I will accept

Comment: @ManishMahajan this has been answered and cannot be put as a new answer again, you can upvote him though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = URL(string: "ftp://user:password@host:port/path")
var data: Data? = nil
if let anUrl = url {
    data = Data(contentsOf: anUrl)
}
```

then you will get the file into `data`

***Note***: I have simply converted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612918/5255016) to Swift

Comment: This will download the file on the main thread. Which will make the app unusable until it's finish. You should never do this.

Comment: @Desdenova yes you are right we can run it in background